# How do you logout/switch accounts?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

Once you are logged in to your datalab instance there doesn't seem to be a way to logout/switch accounts, I tried going from the main "https://datalab.cloud.google.com/" page, but even if I select a different account... when it redirects me to the datalab instance I'm still logged in as my previous account.

Any help / pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a user icon at the top right, clicking that will give you a dropdown menu with a Sign Out option.

Comment: ooo, which version did they add this in?

Comment: try the latest version, it was released just yesterday. there's both a local version that can run entirely on your own machine, and a cloud-based one. check them here: https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts/

Comment: ugh, ya, I wanted to but the startup is now no longer a one-click process, so I've got to schedule some time before I can dive in again. :(